# Docker registry:2 won't start

Tags: docker

I've just setup a new OpenSuse 13.1 server and installed Docker.  I pulled the registry:2 image and when I try running it, I get the following error:

```
93b827525f40c2b8c609115972bc0063c98769434136a54db3a1c77fab011cdc
Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 93b827525f40c2b8c609115972bc0063c98769434136a54db3a1c77fab011cdc: [8] System error: open /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct/system.slice/system.slice/docker-93b827525f40c2b8c609115972bc0063c98769434136a54db3a1c77fab011cdc.scope/cpu.shares: no such file or directory
```

**Edit:**
I did a fresh OS install of openSuse and reinstalled Docker.  Everything worked fine up to that point and I was able to start bash in a container.  Next I tried running registry:2 again and was then faced with the same problem as before.  More importantly, following my failed attempt at running registry, I was no longer able to run bash in a container.  No containers would start any more.  Not sure if registry just isn't compatible with openSuse or if I'm missing something fundamental.

Comment: How are you running the registry? what command?

Comment: Using the command from the documentation `docker run -d -p 5000:5000 registry:2`

Comment: If your other containers are failing also, I would suspect the docker daemon is not working, not specific to registry, can you get other containers working?